# JSON won't validate

Tags: json

I'm trying to get this to validate, it's probably a comma or formatting but I can't work it out and it's driving me insane - It doesn't seem to *fail* initially not sure why it does later on.

For reference: https://umod.org/plugins/server-rewards#adding-an-item

Any help would be appreciated - Thanks in advance.

```
    {
    "items": {
            "lmg.m249_0": {
            "shortname": "lmg.m249",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "M249",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "rifle.l96_0": {
            "shortname": "rifle.l96",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "L96 Rifle",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "rifle.m39_0": {
            "shortname": "rifle.m39",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "M39 Rifle",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "rifle.lr300_0": {
            "shortname": "rifle.lr300",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "LR-300 Assault Rifle",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "rifle.ak_0": {
            "shortname": "rifle.ak",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "Assault Rifle",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "pistol.python_0": {
            "shortname": "pistol.python",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "Python Revolver",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "rocket.launcher_0": {
            "shortname": "rocket.launcher",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "Rocket Launcher",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "multiplegrenadelauncher_0": {
            "shortname": "multiplegrenadelauncher",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "Multiple Grenade Launcher",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "weapon.mod.lasersight_0": {
            "shortname": "weapon.mod.lasersight",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "Weapon Lasersight",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "weapon.mod.silencer_0": {
            "shortname": "weapon.mod.silencer",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "Silencer",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "ammo.rifle_0": {
            "shortname": "ammo.rifle",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "5.56 Rifle Ammo",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "ammo.rifle.hv_0": {
            "shortname": "ammo.rifle.hv",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "HV 5.56 Rifle Ammo",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "ammo.rifle.explosive_0": {
            "shortname": "ammo.rifle.explosive",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "Explosive 5.56 Rifle Ammo",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "ammo.shotgun_0: {
            "shortname": "ammo.shotgun",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "12 Gauge Buckshot",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "ammo.shotgun.slug_0": {
            "shortname": "ammo.shotgun.slug",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "12 Gauge Slug",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "ammo.pistol_0": {
            "shortname": "ammo.pistol",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "Pistol Bullet",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },      
            "ammo.pistol.hv_0": {
            "shortname": "ammo.pistol.hv",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "HV Pistol Ammo",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "ammo.rocket.basic_0": {
            "shortname": "ammo.rocket.basic",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "Rocket",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "ammo.rocket.hv_0": {
            "shortname": "ammo.rocket.hv",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "High Velocity Rocket",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "ammo.rocket.sam_0": {
            "shortname": "ammo.rocket.sam",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "SAM Ammo",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "ammo.grenadelauncher.he_0": {
            "shortname": "ammo.grenadelauncher.he",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "40mm HE Grenade",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "ammo.grenadelauncher.buckshot_0": {
            "shortname": "ammo.grenadelauncher.buckshot",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "40mm Shotgun Round",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        }
    },
    "kits": {},
    "commands": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was the extra `}` above `"kits"`.

```
{
    "items": {
            "lmg.m249_0": {
            "shortname": "lmg.m249",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "M249",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "rifle.l96_0": {
            "shortname": "rifle.l96",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "L96 Rifle",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "rifle.m39_0": {
            "shortname": "rifle.m39",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "M39 Rifle",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "rifle.lr300_0": {
            "shortname": "rifle.lr300",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "LR-300 Assault Rifle",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "rifle.ak_0": {
            "shortname": "rifle.ak",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "Assault Rifle",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "pistol.python_0": {
            "shortname": "pistol.python",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "Python Revolver",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "rocket.launcher_0": {
            "shortname": "rocket.launcher",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "Rocket Launcher",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "multiplegrenadelauncher_0": {
            "shortname": "multiplegrenadelauncher",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "Multiple Grenade Launcher",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "weapon.mod.lasersight_0": {
            "shortname": "weapon.mod.lasersight",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "Weapon Lasersight",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "weapon.mod.silencer_0": {
            "shortname": "weapon.mod.silencer",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "Silencer",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "ammo.rifle_0": {
            "shortname": "ammo.rifle",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "5.56 Rifle Ammo",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "ammo.rifle.hv_0": {
            "shortname": "ammo.rifle.hv",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "HV 5.56 Rifle Ammo",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "ammo.rifle.explosive_0": {
            "shortname": "ammo.rifle.explosive",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "Explosive 5.56 Rifle Ammo",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "ammo.shotgun_0: {
            "shortname": "ammo.shotgun",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "12 Gauge Buckshot",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "ammo.shotgun.slug_0": {
            "shortname": "ammo.shotgun.slug",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "12 Gauge Slug",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "ammo.pistol_0": {
            "shortname": "ammo.pistol",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "Pistol Bullet",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },      
            "ammo.pistol.hv_0": {
            "shortname": "ammo.pistol.hv",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "HV Pistol Ammo",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "ammo.rocket.basic_0": {
            "shortname": "ammo.rocket.basic",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "Rocket",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "ammo.rocket.hv_0": {
            "shortname": "ammo.rocket.hv",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "High Velocity Rocket",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "ammo.rocket.sam_0": {
            "shortname": "ammo.rocket.sam",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "SAM Ammo",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "ammo.grenadelauncher.he_0": {
            "shortname": "ammo.grenadelauncher.he",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "40mm HE Grenade",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
            "ammo.grenadelauncher.buckshot_0": {
            "shortname": "ammo.grenadelauncher.buckshot",
            "customIcon": null,
            "amount": 1,
            "skinId": 0,
            "isBp": false,
            "category": 1,
            "displayName": "40mm Shotgun Round",
            "cost": 100,
            "cooldown": 0
        },
    "kits": {},
    "commands": {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't validate, I must be missing something somewhere - I missed a " on line 146 but still having issues.

Nevermind, added the " and the } back and all fine.